# Does PyTorch Lightning Trainer reset weights?

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

Suppose I pretrain then finetune a model as follows:

```
>>> submodel = SubModel(...)
>>> pretrain_submodel(submodel)
>>> full_model = MyModel(submodel, ...)  # SubModel -> MLP projection head
>>> trainer = pl.Trainer(...)
>>> trainer.fit(full_model, train_finetune_loader, val_finetune_loader)
```

My question is, does the Trainer reset model weights at the beginning? I need to ensure this is not the case. I do not freeze the submodel weights, because I want it to continue training at that point. I cannot find any information on this in the documentation. If someone has the answer, I would truly appreciate it.

Comment: How do you perform the second step of your training? Do you save/load your weights?

Comment: I don't save/load weights, I simply pass the pretrained submodel into a wrapper model, then pass this to the Trainer.

Answer (score 0):

The trainer won't affect your model's weight. 
It will only interact by transferring it to the required device and calling it.